# How can I dynamically adjust a web page between desktops and smartphones?

Tags: html, web

He is my code and I am trying to let my html code to adjust dynamically according to the screen sizes, but my html code doesn't look like it is working. Where should I change in my code?

```html
<body bgcolor="#F6F9FC" width="100%" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
 <div  style="border-width: background-color: #0A2948; 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0px; height: 55px;">
  <center>
  <table width="100%" height="100%">   
   <tr height="55px">
    <td width="100%" bgcolor="#0A2948" style="font: 12pt 'Verdana'; color: white; font-weight: bold;">
     <center>
     <table width="55%">
      <tr>
       <td valign="middle" width="55%" align="left">
        <font color="Orange">T</font>eam<font color="Orange"> M</font>ates
       </td>
       <td valign="middle" align="right" width="5%">
        <img src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/search.jpg' border="0"/>
       </td>
       <td valign="middle" align="left" width="10%" style="font: 10pt 'Verdana'; color: white; font-weight: normal;">
        &nbsp;Project
       </td>
       <td valign="middle" align="right" width="5%">
        <img src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/matesearch.jpg' border="0"/>
       </td>
       <td valign="middle" align="left" width="10%" style="font: 10pt 'Verdana'; color: white; font-weight: normal;">
        &nbsp;Mates
       </td>
       <td valign="middle" align="right" width="5%">
        <img src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/write.jpg' border="0"/>
       </td>
       <td valign="middle" align="left" width="10%" style="font: 10pt 'Verdana'; color: white; font-weight: normal;">
        <a href>&nbsp;Write</a>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     </center>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </center>
 </div> 
 </body>
```

Comment: What you are referring to is responsive web design: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=responsive+web+design+tutorial  Please read some articles about it and come back with your questions.

Comment: What exactly is wrongly rendered ?

Comment: When I open the web page on desktops, it looks ok but I am wasting left and right sides, so as two sides are wasted the page looks very small on smartphones.

Comment: If you want your webpage to adjust to different screen sizes,  ideally, use @media rules.  Here are examples https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 1):

It is not so clear what you are trying to achieve. Using a relative unit such as percentage like you did in your question, tells the browser that an element’s size is relative to that of its parent. And it is working in your example.

Perhaps you are looking for a way to say:

```
if the screen width is less than n, then arrange elements in this fashion
```

Frameworks such as Bootstrap make it easier to accomplish scaling. What they use are called media queries. Here is an example of a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .someClass {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

The latter media query would apply if the screen width is less or equal to 600px.